# STM32F107 read mems mic MP34DT05-A i2s

Tags: c, stm32, i2s, mems

I am working on STM32F107 to read MP34DT05-A mems mic on I2S. I have tried any configuration setting with `pdm2pcm.c` and `i2s.c` but nothing shows the expected result.

The expected result is positive int value. This is what i did so far:

- `i2s3` (`SPI3`) set to master RX mode, standar msb, format 16b extended with audio freq 8k.
- DMA2 channel 1 halfword, circular and very high priority.
- PDM filter set to LSB, big endian, decimation by 64.
- In main.c i'm calling it like this:

> ```
>    usb_printf("\nMEAS MIC..");
>    __HAL_RCC_CRC_CLK_ENABLE();
>    HAL_I2S_Receive_DMA(&hi2s3, pdm_buff, 16);
>    usb_printf("\nPDM BUFF: ");
>    usb_printf(pdm_buff);
>    while (1) {
>          uint16_t *pcm_out;
>          uint16_t *pdm_out;
>          memcpy(cbuff, pdm_buff, sizeof(pdm_buff));
>          PDM_Filter(&cbuff[0], &pcm_buff[0], &PDM1_filter_handler);
>          usb_printf("pcm_buff: 0x%04X  ", pcm_buff[0]);
>          usb_printf("pcm_buff int: %d", pcm_buff[0]);
>    }
>    delay_ms(500);
> ```

And the result is something like this:

> ```
>  pcm_buff: 0xFFFF828F  pcm_buff int: -32113
>  pcm_buff: 0xFFFFA2E3  pcm_buff int: -23837
>  pcm_buff: 0xFFFFB379  pcm_buff int: -19591
>  pcm_buff: 0xFFFFBFFF  pcm_buff int: -16385
> ```

Am I missing something? Or is there any missed configuration?

Comment: The types and declarations of all these variables is fundamental information, please post a [mcve].

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. edited. Am I missing something on my question?

Comment: You just removed even more code... we need more info, not less. It's not meaningful to view _any_ C code without knowing the types of all variables involved. Also you mention big endian, is there a conversion from little to big somewhere?